# How to check the data type of elements in an array C

Tags: c, arrays, types

trying to error check the elements put into an array to make sure that they are

1)between 1 and 42

2)of data type int

any suggestions on how to do so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6

int main()
{
int i;
int numbers[SIZE];

 for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    printf("Enter number %d of your 6 numbers, between 1 and 42(integers only)!",i+1);
    scanf("%d",*(numbers+i));
    if(*(numbers+i)<1 || *(numbers+i)>42 || *(numbers+i) != /*data type int*/)
    {
        printf("Invlaid input");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Valid input");
    }
}

getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once elements are in array of type `int[]`, they cannot be of any other than `int` type.

Comment: when a character type is entered my program crashes , any way to prevent this?

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: You must read user input as string, then check the string for valid integer representation: each char must be '0'-'9'. Then use `atoi()` function to convert it to an `int`, and only then check the result to be in the range 1-42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only error is - you are passing to `scanf` some indeterminate value which are considered as address by `scanf` - this leads to undefined behavior.

Correct one,

```
scanf("%d",(numbers+i));
```

Also you don't need to check for it - the compiler wil make sure of it. Once you declare an array of type `T` it is of type `T` - every element of it is. This is the very characteristic of array.

The point you want to say that whether user entered integer or not - which can be checked by checking the return value of `scanf`.

Something like,

```
if( scanf("%d",&numbers[i]) != 1){
   fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

What else you can do? Instead of exiting you can consume those bad inputs from `stdin` which `scanf` couldn't take because those don't match what is being expected by `scanf`'s `%d` format specifier.

But if you are planning for that level of input validation - I can suggest you to use `fgets` and `strtol` combination. You take a line input and then parse it using `strtol`. `strtol` has rich error control. ( I have intentionally avoided the mention of `atoi` because it provides no error checking).